# issue with insertBefore()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a small object which has to append new rows to a table.. It works fine in most cases, but if there is a table inside some of the rows (in the "root" table) the object doesn't append to the proper table!?

I have been doing a bit of debugging and found the line where it all goes wrong.. If DEBUG is set and the line with insertBefore() is omitted the object appends to the proper table

```
var List = new function(){
    this.append_row = function(row, tbl, index){
        if(DEBUG){
            index = -1;
        }

        if(index == 0){
            row.prependTo(tbl);
        }
        else if(index > 0){
            var elm = $('tr', tbl);
            if(elm.length > index){
                row.insertBefore(elm.eq(index)); // the issue is in this line
            }
            else{
                row.appendTo(tbl);
            }
        }
        else{
            row.appendTo(tbl);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: very confusing question...please re-word it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because this:

```
var elm = $('tr', tbl);
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
var elm = $(tbl).find('tr');
```

So it will locate all nested `<tr>` elements in any nested `<table>`.

So you could do this:

```
var elm = $(tbl.rows); // if `tbl` is the DOM element
```

or this:

```
var elm = $(tbl[0].rows); // if `tbl` is a jQuery object
```

Now `elm` is a reference only to the `rows` of the `tbl`, and not any nested `<table>` elements.

Comment: `tbl` is a jquery object.. When `var elm = $(tbl[0].rows);` is replaced rows are appended to the proper table but now they are always appended last (as -1)

Comment: @clarkk: Try doing: `elm.eq(index).before( row );`

Comment: ok.. only if index is 0 the row is appended in the proper place

Comment: @clarkk: [In this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7yPMb/), which is the same as your original, except removing the `DEBUG` and adding my fix, it seems to work well. Could you provide a jsFiddle that demonstrates the incorrect behavior?